# Find actual size of NamedSize value

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How do I look up the pixel value of a [NamedSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.NamedSize?view=xamarin-forms) value?

I want to set the font size on a `TimePicker` but doing it on the control in XML has no effect.

To set the font size in a renderer I need to know the pixel size of `Small` so that the font's size is consistent with my other form elements that work correctly.

Comment: Also, don't forget that Xamarin Forms is all open source, you can always take a look at the source code and see what is being set, [Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/9fe5372c1d80ca8fcff0c4fc397d25f91f6b61d3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/FontExtensions.cs) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [Device.GetNamedSize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#font-size)

```
label.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label));
```